# Why can't I drag object from the Object Library to the View Controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just started learning how to code Swift while using the Xcode environment. I have been taking a course on Udemy. Every lesson requires me to make a new single page application to try and learn a new skill. I haven't had a problem in following the instructions and creating the apps for many months. Recently, however, I've run into the following problem... I  can't drag objects from the Object Library to the View Controller in the Main.storyboard page. I restarted my computer and Xcode, but the problem is still not going away. I deleted the app where the problem was occurring and tried opening up a new app, but the problem persists. Is it something in the settings of the app?

Comment: Maybe explain what "I can't drag objects" really means? You have lost the ability to move your arm? The object does not react when you click? You can click and drag, but when you release, the object doesn't appear in your view controller? Without a more precise problem, it's hard to answer. What version of macOS? What version of Xcode?